# Linq two classes with foreign key

Tags: c#

I have this  two table

```
class A
{
    int IdA;
    String DescA;
}

class B
{
    int IdB;
    String DescB;
    int IdA;
}
```

IdA in "B" is a foreign key for class A, and I have a function that return a list of "A" `getListA()` and with this function i have to count how many "B" that has DescB empty, this is what i did:

```
var emptyDescB = getListA().Where(p => p.B.All(k => k.DescB != 0)).count();
```

but this isnt working how it should :/ . any idea guys can i count how many empty DescB that i have?

Comment: How is it not working? In your classes, the fields should be public if you're trying to access them from other classes

Comment: Where is a navigation property `B` in your `A` class? Otherwise how would code `.Where(p => p.B.All(k =...)`  work ?

Comment: How can `p.B` exist in the return type of `getListA()` if you're saying that it's returning a list of `A`?

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx) on how to set up your model classes so the foreign key relationship is modelled correctly.

Comment: @phate01 I'm using Entity framework so i do find also "A"

Answer (score 0):

*The C# classes and the linq query you gave as an example don't match, so this answer is a bit of an assumption.*

The classes below set up a one-to-many relationship between `A` and `B`; i.e. where each `A` instance can have *multiple* child `B` instances.

```cs
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Children { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual A Parent { get; set; }
}
```

.. and then given the function `getListA()` which returns a list of instances of `A`, you can find the "number of instances of `B` where `Description` is empty" with:

```cs
var numberOfBWithEmptyDescriptions = getListA()
        .SelectMany(a => a.Children) // .. ignore the 'A' instances, just access their children, the instances of B
        .Count (b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Description)); // .. count the intances of B with an empty description
```